# Efficient Kalman filter implementation on gridded data

Tags: python, numpy, kalman-filter

I have written a very simple Kalman filter that operates on time series (with data gaps included). It works nicely, but I happen to have a *data cube* of data (an array of shape `Nt, Ny, Nx`, say), and I want to apply my temporal Kalman filter for each pixel in the data cube. I have done the obvious (loop over the last two dimensions), but this takes quite a long time.

Ultimately, I always end up having to extract data from individual "pixels", and constructing the relevant matrices/vectors, so the process is quite slow (note that the gaps in each individual time series are different, and typically, so is the H matrix that links the state to the observations). I'm not familiar with cython, and it might help (only that I'm not familiar with it).

I was just wondering whether a clever rephrasing of the problem, or a clever data structure, might allow to do the temporal filtering far more efficiently. I'd rather this only used numpy/scipy, and not OpenCV, as otherwise it's a hassle depending on an extra package.

Comment: "The obvious" is *don't loop*. Use vectorized NumPy operations instead.

Comment: @larsmans Due to the nature of the problem, I can't see how vectorised operations can be made to fit this problem (you need to build matrices etc.)

Comment: Then you need to first profile the program to find out what's expensive ([Kern's line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) is great for that), then post the parts of the code that are slow and ask how they can be vectorized. As it stands, this question cannot properly be answered.

Comment: Can you post your code you got so far, so we can see how we can help?

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple vectorised Kalman filter like this for processing movie frames. It's pretty quick but currently limited to 1D inputs and outputs, and it doesn't do EM optimisation of any of the filter parameters.

```
import numpy as np

def runkalman(y, RQratio=10., meanwindow=10):
    """
    A simple vectorised 1D Kalman smoother

    y       Input array. Smoothing is always applied over the first 
            dimension

    RQratio     An estimate of the ratio of the variance of the output 
            to the variance of the state. A higher RQ ratio will 
            result in more smoothing.

    meanwindow  The initial mean and variance of the output are 
            estimated over this number of timepoints from the start 
            of the array

    References:
        Ghahramani, Z., & Hinton, G. E. (1996). Parameter Estimation for
        Linear Dynamical Systems.
        http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5997

        Yu, B., Shenoy, K., & Sahani, M. (2004). Derivation of Extented
        Kalman Filtering and Smoothing Equations.
        http://www-npl.stanford.edu/~byronyu/papers/derive_eks.pdf
    """

    x,vpre,vpost = forwardfilter(y, RQratio=RQratio, meanwindow=meanwindow)
    x,v = backpass(x, vpre, vpost)
    x[np.isnan(x)] = 0.
    return x

def forwardfilter(y, RQratio=10., meanwindow=10):
    """
    the Kalman forward (filter) pass:

        xpost,Vpre,Vpost = forwardfilter(y)
    """

    y = np.array(y,copy=False,subok=True,dtype=np.float32)

    xpre = np.empty_like(y)
    xpost = np.empty_like(y)
    Vpre = np.empty_like(y)
    Vpost = np.empty_like(y)
    K = np.empty_like(y)

    # initial conditions
    pi0 = y[:meanwindow].mean(0)
    ystd = np.std(y,0)
    R = ystd * ystd
    Q = R / RQratio
    V0 = Q

    xpre[0] = xpost[0] = pi0
    Vpre[0] = Vpost[0] = V0
    K[0] = 0

    # loop forwards through time
    for tt in xrange(1, y.shape[0]):

        xpre[tt] = xpost[tt-1]
        Vpre[tt] = Vpost[tt-1] + Q

        K[tt] = Vpre[tt] / (Vpre[tt] + R)
        xpost[tt] = xpre[tt] + K[tt] * (y[tt] - xpre[tt])
        Vpost[tt] = Vpre[tt] - K[tt] * (Vpre[tt])

    return xpost,Vpre,Vpost

def backpass(x, Vpre, V):
    """ 
    the Kalman backward (smoothing) pass:

        xpost,Vpost = backpass(x,Vpre,V)
    """

    xpost = np.empty_like(x)
    Vpost = np.empty_like(x)
    J = np.empty_like(x)

    xpost[-1] = x[-1]
    Vpost[-1] = V[-1]

    # loop backwards through time
    for tt in xrange(x.shape[0]-1, 0, -1):
        J[tt-1] = V[tt-1] / Vpre[tt]
        xpost[tt-1] = x[tt-1] + J[tt-1] * (xpost[tt] - x[tt-1])
        Vpost[tt-1] = V[tt-1] + J[tt-1] * (Vpost[tt] - Vpre[tt]) * J[tt-1]

    return xpost,Vpost
```

If anyone knows of a vectorised Kalman smoother implementation in Python that supports multidimensional inputs/outputs and EM parameter optimisation, I'd love to hear about it! I made a feature request to the [PyKalman](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman) maintainers, but they said that clarity was a higher priority than speed.

Comment: if you have such a "clarity" algorithm looping over array indices and want to have it run fast, have a look into fortran and f2py (which is part of the scipy/numpy universe). The code is essentially the same as your python code. I made once a comparison of different speed-up approaches for my mates which also covers fortran. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5774959

Comment: @P.R. I'm not sure what you mean - the code you linked to has nothing to do with Kalman filters

Comment: no, but it shows how to convert a loopy numpy code into a Fortran code that runs very quickly, while not creating strange dependencies. If you do not care about dependencies and want the code just to be faster with little (actually no) recoding, check out the numba part of that notebook.

Comment: @P.R. The 1D Kalman filter already involves a fair amount of vectorised computations (matrix multiplication etc.), and is therefore not particularly suited for LLVM. It would also require a substantial amount of work to re-write some or all of it in Fortran. I honestly think the best strategy in this case would be to think carefully about the dimensionality of each of the intermediate variables, and use Numpy's broadcasting rules to apply the computations across any additional dimension(s) of the input array.

Comment: @ali_m Quite true, it turns out that my problem is actually quite simple to solve using broadcasting, as some of the matrices effectively evaluate to scalars (1x1 matrices), simplifying things quite substantially!

Comment: this actually sounds a nice solution, with a little bit of Cython it will be as fast as it can.

Comment: @dashesy My comments about rewriting parts of the filter in Fortran also apply to Cython. By all means have a go, but you're unlikely to see big performance gains for your effort, since the current version is already vectorized.

Comment: @ali_m Yes, also I think the initial should be this `ystd = np.std(y[:meanwindow], 0)` according to the doc.